# Estimating Logit Interaction Coefficients: the Second cross derivative

Tags: logistic, interaction, derivative

I have been working on a mixed effects statistical model that proposes a three-way interaction of continuous predictors on a binary variable in lme4. The general outline of the code is as follows:

```
model <- glmer(DV ~ var1*var2*var3 + (var1*var2 | ID), family = binomial, optimizer = bobyqa)
```

However, a recent review for my paper came back that I cannot interpret the interaction terms as they are inappropriately calculated as outlined in:

Ai, C., & Norton, E. C. (2003). Interaction terms in logit and probit models. Economics letters, 80(1), 123-129.

Instead, the correct calculation is

[image]

where Phi is the standard normal cumulative distribution

I am very surprised by this as I have taken multiple statistics classes and this is the first I had heard of this. As far as I can tell, the issue comes from an inappropriate estimate of error due to the asymptotic nature of the probability space in logistic (and other non-linear) models. However, I am unsure if this issue still persists in modern statistical packages and am unsure of exactly how to implement the formulas suggested in the paper. There is a lot of discussion of this topic in Stata forums that seem to have been resolved through Stata updates since that paper was published. However, any packages that were written for R (e.g., intEff) meant to address this problem no longer work that I have found. So, my questions are:

1. is this issue still relevant in lme4 estimations of non-linear interaction terms ?
2. is the issue and solution relevant for mixed models ?
3. can anyone help me understand explicitly what I need to calculate for the interaction terms? My distance from calculus makes interpretation of the above equation difficult (Equation 2 from the paper).

Any documentation you can point me to would be greatly beneficial. Thank you in advance.